Impossible to load latest Akka from SBT with Scala
I load some Akka libraries here, in fact the only dependencies in my project. It is Scala based and very simple and here's the snipped of my build.sbt:
scalaVersion := "3.4.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.6.3",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.6.3"
)


and I get this when I do sbt assembly:
[info] welcome to sbt 1.10.0 (Oracle Corporation Java 22.0.2)
[info] loading settings for project genera-build from assembly.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from ...
[info] loading settings for project genera from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to Genera (in build file:/Users/mjstwo/Documents/Vooomp/Genera/)
[info] Updating ...
[info] Resolved ... dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-spray-json_3:10.6.3
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/mjstwo/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.akka/akka-http-spray-json_3/10.6.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-spray-json_3/10.6.3/akka-http-spray-json_3-10.6.3.pom
[error]   not found: https://dl.bintray.com/guardsquare/proguard/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-spray-json_3/10.6.3/akka-http-spray-json_3-10.6.3.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/mjstwo/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-http-spray-json_3/10.6.3/akka-http-spray-json_3-10.6.3.pom


Why is this happening?
Thos libraries load just fine so I suspect something went haywire with the last few iterations of Akka.
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.6.0-M1",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.6.0-M1"

But not the latest!!!!

These Akka libraries are not published to Maven Central since September 2023, likely due to the license change.
They are however available by using Akka repository at https://repo.akka.io/maven/, that you have to add in your Maven/SBT settings or in the project itself.
See:

versions available in Maven Central
versions available in Akka

